# How to copy all account balances from main network to a private chain?

Tags: private-blockchain, json-rpc, synchronization, balances

So I want to have a playground where all accounts have same balance as on mainnet, yet I do not have access to a fully synchronized node. All I want are account-balance pairs to be synchronized, no other data if possible. How one can get all account-balance data and apply it to a private locally hosted network (where we have an account with nearly infinite balance)?

Comment: you can fork a blockchain with ganache or hardhat and play with it. the contacts, addresses and all balances will be the same.

Comment: @MajdTL: The problem is that this forks into a single node fake network, while I want to fork into geth based one

Comment: okay idk if there is an easy solution. a limited solution would be to get the balances of as many accounts as you can and then place them in the gensis file of geth and start a new private network.